# Using an object in a method by passing it as a parameter

Tags: java, class, methods, instantiation, invoke

I'm facing a situation that involves class and methods.

To make it simple, imagine you have 2 classes: A and B

In the class A, I have a method called, lets say, "jumpOnOtherClass".
In the class B, I have another method called "doThings".

I'd like the class A method to take as argument any object of any class, so that it first checks if the object is null (so it can creates a new instance of the object passed), and then execute a method of the object's class.

Here is an example code:

```
class MyMainClass
{
  private A objectA = new A();
  private B objectB;

  public void main()
  {
    this.objectA.jumpOnOtherClass(this.objectB,"doThings");
  }
}

class A
{
  public void jumpOnOtherClass(Object objectFromAnyClass, String methodToInvoke)
  {
    if(objectFromAnyClass == null) objectFromAnyClass = new DefaultConstructorOfB();

    objectFromAnyClass.getMethod(methodToInvoke);
  }
}

class B
{
  public void doThings()
  {
    //Do some stuff here
  }
}
```

I know there are exception to take in consideration but for the example we'll assume that
the class, and the methods exist and are found :)

I tried things with "java.lang.reflect" but it seems not to be the good way to achieve what I try to do...

Any help would be really nice!

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem is that if the reference is null, you cannot really know the class of the "object" at runtime, so you will need to fix this by providing additional information.

I suggest this approach (it does involve reflection):

```
public <T> void jumpOnOtherClass(T objectFromAnyClass, Class<T> classType, String methodToInvoke)
            throws
            NoSuchMethodException,
            IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException,
            InstantiationException
    {
        if(objectFromAnyClass == null) 
            objectFromAnyClass = classType.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

        classType.getMethod(methodToInvoke).invoke(objectFromAnyClass);
    }
```

and use it like this:

```
jumpOnOtherClass(this.objectB, B.class, "doThings");
```

Comment: hm... it looks like something i tried before and when I try the code, it throws a "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ok$B.<init>()
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
 at ok$A.jumpOnOtherClass(ok.java:41)
 at ok.setup(ok.java:27)
 at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2432)
 at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1547)
 at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:313)"

Comment: Wich for me, means it can't find the default constructor....so in class B, I declared a constructor with no parameters but it still fails... any idea about that?

Comment: Oh! and if I declare the B object in the beginning (as I did for A) and if I jump the part where it instantiate the object if its null, then it works ;)

Comment: I tested it now and it seems to work (as it should). My guess is that the Processing framework causes the problem. Are you using the Processing IDE or manually including the library? The Processing IDE modifies your code significantly when you build your project.

Comment: I use processing IDE. So I exported the sketch as a *.java and it seems that the problem comes from the "path" of the class B: when it comes to get its constructor, we take it from the classType object. When I print out the value of it, it says "ok$B" ("ok" is the name of the sketch). So, the problem could be coming from the fact that processing embed the class as nested class. A solution could be to get the full "path" of the class B so it could find its default constructor (I tried to write the "empty" default constructor of B, it's all the same, getConstructor() crashes...)

Comment: try adding the keyword `static` before the declaration of class B (static class B), as the default constructor of an inner class takes a reference to the outer class object behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but it looks like you may be looking for a way to differentiate between classes initially passed as Objects? You could use the instanceof keyword, and then risk some casting exceptions

```
class MyMainClass
{
private A objectA = new A();
private B objectB;

public void main()
{
   this.objectA.jumpOnOtherClass(this.objectB,"doThings");
}
}

class A
{
  public void jumpOnOtherClass(Object objectFromAnyClass, String methodToInvoke)
  {
    if(objectFromAnyClass == null) objectFromAnyClass = new DefaultConstructorOfB();
    else if (objectFromAnyClass instanceof B) {
         if (methodToInvoke.equals("doThings")) 
            ((B) objectFromAnyClass).doThings();
    }
  }
}

class B
{
  public void doThings()
  {
    //Do some stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: May be a solution, but we are still limited by the name of the constructor.  So maybe instead of using "new DefaultConstructor()", we could use something like Class.getConstructor(). But again... it crashes and says that it can't find the default constructor of the given class :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I get it works finally! So here is the final code:

```
class A
{
  public <T> void jumpOnOtherClass(T objectFromAnyClass, Class<T> classType, String methodToInvoke) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException
  {
    if(objectFromAnyClass == null)
    {
      println("instantiating");
      objectFromAnyClass = classType.newInstance();
    }

    println("getting the method");
    classType.getMethod(methodToInvoke).invoke(objectFromAnyClass);

    println("It works :D");
  }
}

static class B
{  
  public void doThings()
  {
    println("message from class B");
  }
}
```

The problem was actually coming from the class nesting made by processing (and in general, any class nesting). I removed the "getConstructor()" from the line where it was checking if the object b was null.

Maybe someone could explain under this post why does removing this method made everything working... I'm gonna try to understand and if I have something about that, it'll be posted down here!

Again, thanks a lot to you guys for helping :D

Have a nice day!

Larry.K

Comment: I am glad you fixed it! Check the last comment on my post, I wrote it before seeing your updated answer. Hope that explains it. Since the problem was coming from Processing IDE, my answer should work without issues for someone who is searching for the same solution but in plain Java. Please consider marking my answer as the solution for the next guys that stumble upon a similar issue. Have a good day!

Comment: I have a last question about it: Is there another way to do same thing, instantiate and call method of any class that is not static? (So instead of instantiating "static class B", we would instantiate "class B"). If my sketch calls processing native methods, class B can't be marked "static".

Comment: sure. instead of `classType.getDeclaredConstructor()` in my answer, search for the constructor with the "hidden" parameter as such: `classType.getDeclaredConstructor(SuperClass.class)`, where SuperClass is, well, the superclass (in your case, the name of the sketch). then call the `newInstance(superClassInstance)`. you need to get the superClassInstance, and depending on the context, this might be the `this` keyword in the superclass or if you are in another inner nested class, use `SuperClass.this` (again the name of the sketch)

Comment: Yep! It worked! I'm gonna write down the working code here too! Thanks a lot Halex! Huge kiss (with masks and 1 meter to one each other) from France!

Comment: Glad I could help! :D